# Specific word for discrimination based on religion

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, analogy

How would one refer to discrimination purely based on religion? Is there a single word?
For example discrimination based on sex is often referred to as sexism, discrimination based on race is often referred to as racism.

I found one similar question online, [at Yahoo Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091107032207AAycqRx), but unfortunately as expected the quality of the answers is laughable, and outdated.

Comment: What's wrong with the accepted answer from that link? “You'd just call it _religious intolerance_ but there are specific names for each religion e.g. Christianophobia, Anti-Semitism, Islamophobia, Anti-Mormonism etc.” That sounds spot-on to me.

Comment: Agree with @BraddSzonye -- and unfortunately antitheism is already taken. (The Yahoo Answers respondant who suggests "theism" is way off the mark).

Comment: I have heard the word "faithism" used in informal contexts.

Comment: How about a neologism like say ... "*theophobe*"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Religious discrimination*** is the most widely use term, and there doesn't appear to a well accepted single-word term for this. Although ***religionism*** is most often described as a fervent religious zeal, it can also be used to describe religious discrimination:

> 1. excessive religious ardour or zeal
> 2. extreme piety
> 3. discrimination or prejudice on the basis of religion or religious beliefs.

…according to [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/religionism) at least—I'm unable to find another source for this usage.

On a side note, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Religionism&redirect=no) 's entry for *religionism* redirects to *religious discrimination*.

Answer (score 0):

In some contexts, I would think that [antitheism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antitheism) might work.

Comment: I'm not so sure. _Racism_ tends to indicate a bias towards/against a specific race. _Antitheism_ on the other hand tends to indicate a bias against all religions (or at least against theism, ie the belief in god or gods).

Comment: the way the question is worded, it seems to be looking for a categorical word -- racism is bias based on race in general (it doesn't specify which race and can be used for bias against any race in particular). Antitheism would be against any/all religions in general.

Answer (score 0):

"Religious discrimination" is an established phrasal noun and should be perfectly adequate!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_discrimination

Comment: Welcome to [english.se]. Your answer is welcome. Ideally, all answers are supported by citing supporting evidence such as a good desk reference. If you can, please add that to your answer. Thanks.